# UIPickerView can't pre select a row

Tags: swift3, uipickerview

For the app I'm working on, what I'd like would be that when the view show, the pickerview view is already at a certain row, and that I don't need to touch it (unless I need it).

I know there are plenty of question like this one on SO, but I couldn't find my answer.

Right now here is what's done and what works:

- When the view appears, the UIPickerView is at the preselected row (ie 2nd for example)
- I can change it to another one and save it.

But, when I try to save without touching it, it's like nothing is selected. I've to touche the PickerView to select the row I want, even if it's the one I "Selected" at first.

I'm selected the row with :

```
pickerViewAction.selectRow(inPickerViewAction.index(of: temp?[0] as! String)!, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

Where `inPickerViewAction.index(of: temp?[0] as! String)!` is the row I need.

How I test if a row is selected (maybe my problem comes from here, I don't know...)

```
let selectedValue1 = inPickerViewAction[Row]
switch selectedValue1 {
    case "Email" :
        //Doing my stuff
    case "Commande http", name1, name2, name3, name4, name5:
        //Doing my stuff
    default:
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Nothing selected", message: "You must select an item before saving", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break
```

Right now if I don't touch the UIPickerView, I've the UIAlert that show.

If anyone have an idea, that'd be great. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose the first row for example : 
you need to call this two :

```
//first call : 
pickerViewAction.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
// then call the delegate : didSelectRow
pickerView(pickerViewAction, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 0)
```